# Grafana invalid API key with newly created key

Tags: authentication, grafana, grafana-api

I embed some grafana charts in my web application. Right now, I have to login on my app, and then login on my grafana charts within the app to get the data. I would like to automatically log my users to grafana once they are connected to my app, for ease of use, but also because I don't want to grant them access to grafana.

I was thinking of saving the grafana credentials I created per client within my application backend and then send an auth request to grafana once the users have successfully connected using their app credentials.

I have looked at this [link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/auth/), but I don't really get it. I created an api key (thinking of saving it in the backend rather than the credentials) and tested it by using a chart url in postman, but I got a 401 "invalid API key".

Can anyone explain this to me please ?

(I have auth.anonymous disabled, and auth.basic enabled)